# How can i render templates on the basis of conditions in django DetailView

Tags: django

I have tried overriding get_templates_name().But it is not helping me out.

```
def get_template_names(self):
    theme = Themes.objects.filter(theme_creator=self.request.user)
    for t in theme:
        if t.technology_theme == True:
            return ["landing/preview/preview1.html/"]       
        elif t.default_theme == True:
            return  ["landing/categories/technology/technology1.html/"]
```

Comment: It shouldn't have `/` at the end. Paths should be relative in your `TEMPLATE` `DIRS`. If that didn't help, provide your `Themes` model and how templates are located in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a variable like

```
 if t.technology_theme == True:
     template_name = "landing/preview/preview1.html"
 elif t.default_theme == True:
     template_name = "landing/categories/technology/technology1.html"
```

and return template_name form your view like

In CBV:

```
template_name=template_name
```

In FBV:

```
retrun render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: Can try once using DetailView.

Answer (score 1):

Inside get_object(), or get_context_data(), you can define the template name like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.template_name = 'your_template.html'
    return context
```

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question.